# How to convert the asp .Net website folder to the web application in C#?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, web-applications, iis-6

Question 1:

I have the ASP .Net website folder and want to convert it to the web application projects for ASP .Net, but I find out the website UI elements can't inherit in the web application projects. The complier shows "This UI can't find out.", and "This UI ID has two objects."

Could tell me how to solve this problems?

Question 2:

I find out the memory of the service is too huge when the client side website selects the huge data on the client website, and exports the huge data. These also show the memory error message on the client side website.

How to stop the aspnet_wp.exe running of the service side from the client side website in ASP.Net in C#?

Running environment:

Windows 7 x86

.Net framework 4.0

Thanks.

Comment: For Q1, have you went through the walkthrough at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx?

Comment: @junkangli I try it, but the error messages also exist.

Comment: Will you be able to provide the exact message of the error you encountered?